# The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

Tags: c#, iis, event-log, iis-8

I am getting error:

> The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be
>   searched. Inaccessible logs: Security

When I run below code to capture errors on Win 2K12 R2 server IIS 8.5

```
EventLog elog = new EventLog();
EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyApp", "Application");
EventLog.WriteEntry(Source, swError.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
```

I've given full access to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog` but it is not working still. What shall I do to fix it?

Comment: For what user you have given full access to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog`?

Comment: network service & IIS User

Comment: You will probably need to add it for your [application pool identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities)

Comment: Did my answer solve the problem or not? Please report if there's a different problem.

Comment: Check this **[The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security.](https://debug.to/2683/source-found-but-some-all-event-logs-could-not-searched-inaccessible-logs-security)**

Answer (score 92, accepted):

See [creating a registry key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286060/what-do-i-need-to-change-to-alllow-my-iis7-asp-net-3-5-application-to-create-an/7848414#7848414).

This problem can occur not only due to permissions, but also due to event source key missing because it wasn't registered successfully (you need admin privileges to do it - if you just open Visual Studio as usual and run the program normally it won't be enough). Make sure that your event source "MyApp" is actually registered, i.e. that it appears in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application`.

From [MSDN EventLog.CreateEventSource()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2awhba7a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> To create an event source in Windows Vista and later or Windows Server
>   2003, you must have administrative privileges.

So you must either run the event source registration code as an admin (also, check if the source already exists before - see the above MSDN example) or you can manually add the key to the registry:

1. create a regkey `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\Application\MyApp`;
2. inside, create a string value `EventMessageFile` and set its value to e.g. `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\EventLogMessages.dll`

Comment: If you're using a newer framework, the `EventMessageFile` value might be `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll`

Comment: I was looking for the registered name of my application, but the missing registry key is in fact "My App".

Comment: Bottom line:  it fails on `EventLog.CreateEventSource()` because of admin privileges being required to create the key.  He either needs to run the app with said privileges (or Visual Studio, if debugging when running), or create the key ahead of time & check for it and not create it, if it's already there.

Comment: This is not a right solution, especially for end-user.

Comment: You have to temporarily disable impersonate in the code, for more details Check this **[The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched. Inaccessible logs: Security.](https://debug.to/2683/source-found-but-some-all-event-logs-could-not-searched-inaccessible-logs-security)**

Answer (score 52):

I got this error when running Visual Studio.  By [running Visual Studio as Administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8825573/c-sharp-eventlog-inaccessible-log#8825621) the application was able to access the Security logs as it then had sufficient permissions (thus preventing the error).

Comment: Even with VS (Running as Admin), I had to add the registry entry.

Comment: Running as admin worked for me.
Windows 8.1
VS 2017 Community

Comment: Running VS as admin worked for me (Win10, VS 2019)

Comment: This is not a right solution, especially for end-user.

Answer (score 14):

I know, I am a little late to the party ... what happen a lot, you just use default settings in your *app pool* in IIS. In IIS Administration utility, go to `app pools->select pool-->advanced settings->Process Model/Identity` and select a user identity which has right permissions. By default it is set to `ApplicationPoolIdentity`. If you're developer, you most likely admin on your machine, so you can select your account to run app pool. On the deployment servers, let admins to deal with it.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever you start Visual Studio run it as administrator. It works for me.

Comment: Who said "Visual studio"? You said! question has no mention of this

Comment: I also had to run the VS developer command prompt as administrator when I saw this error there.

Answer (score 6):

try giving AppPool ID or Network Services whichever applicable access HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\eventlog\security also. I was getting the same error .. this worked for me. See the error is also saying that the inaccessible logs are Security Logs.

I also gave permission in eventlog\application .

I gave full access everywhere.

Answer (score 6):

Locally I **run visual studio with admin rights** and the error was gone.

If you get this error in task scheduler you have to **check the option run with high privileges**.

Comment: Who said "Visual studio"? You said! question has no mention of this

Comment: If your deploying a service using  Visual studio 2017 >> Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017 >> installutil.exe you get this error that exactly matches this pages title, hence it is a reasonably good place to put this answer (for Visual Studio users). When I ran the command prompt again as administrator it cure the error.

Answer (score 2):

It could also be because, it might not be able to found the .dll file required.
Either the file is not in the folder or is renamed.
I faced the same issue and found that .dll file was missing in my bin folder some how.

Answer (score 2):

Use **NetworkService** as Identity value in the application pool advanced settings when you are debugging in Visual Studio. **ApplicationPoolIdentity** is working if you open the site directly from the browser (or go to virtual directory in IIS and use Browse option at right).

Answer (score 0):

I recently started receiving this error inside of my internal NLog failures log, with Visual Studio 2013.  The solution has been using NLog v2.0.0 for several years.  Within the last month, our main log stopped working.  To fix this I updated NLog to the newest version (v3.1.0) via Nuget.  The security exception is now gone and ALL of the log messages are appearing again.

Additionally, I later found another Security exception and was able to fix it by following the instructions on this [post in another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3138269/2615152).